# "navigation" is of type string, expected sap.f.LayoutType for property "layout" of Element

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to build an app with flexible column layout and routing according to the tutorial on page https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/a59b3de038874f879cf20bfc3287bd7c.

The app is very simple and it looks as the following:
[image]

The `default` button press event on the detail page is implemented as:

```
onPress: function (evt) {
    this.oRouter.navTo("navigation", {
        layout: fioriLibrary.LayoutType.EndColumnFullScreen
    });
}
```

After clicking, it shows me the error message:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

The routing part from the manifest file:

```
        "routing": {
            "config": {
                "routerClass": "sap.f.routing.Router",
                "viewType": "XML",
                "viewPath": "io.example.fcl.view",
                "controlId": "flexibleColumnLayout",
                "transition": "slide",
                "bypassed": {},
                "async": true
            },
            "routes": [
                {
                    "pattern": ":layout:",
                    "name": "master",
                    "target": [
                        "master",
                        "detail"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "pattern": "{layout}",
                    "name": "detail",
                    "target": [
                        "master",
                        "detail"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "pattern": "navigation",
                    "name": "navigation",
                    "target": "navigation",
                    "layout": "EndColumnFullScreen"
                }
            ],
            "targets": {
                "master": {
                    "viewName": "Master",
                    "controlAggregation": "beginColumnPages"
                },
                "detail": {
                    "viewName": "Detail",
                    "controlAggregation": "midColumnPages"
                },
                "navigation": {
                    "viewName": "Navigation",
                    "controlAggregation": "endColumnPages"
                }
            }
        }
```

The resource can be found on https://github.com/softshipper/fcl.

Comment: All of your routes are the same. You can move your navigation route to the beginning so it will match at least that one. Otherwise `navigation` has the same pattern as `:layout:` (and `{layout}`) and this will lead to wrong behaviour.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot for your help/